# how to get a field participating in 'n' records in a file using awk when some other field has same value in all those 'n' records?

Tags: bash, awk

Suppose I have a file like below :

```
    *kaustav,man,dip,gk,buro,alu,tulu,ritesh,referee,champa,10
    tulu,dip,gk,buro,alu,tulu,ritesh,referee,champa,man,11
    tulu,man,gk,buro,alu,tulu,ritesh,referee,champa,dip,12
    kaustav,man,dip,buro,alu,tulu,ritesh,referee,champa,gk,13
    kaustav,man,dip,gk,buro,alu,tulu,ritesh,referee,champa,14
    kaustav,man,dip,gk,buro,alu,tulu,ritesh,referee,champa,15
    kaustav,man,dip,gk,buro,alu,tulu,ritesh,referee,champa,20
    man,kaustav,man,dip,gk,buro,alu,tulu,ritesh,referee,champa,21
    kaustav,man,dip,gk,buro,alu,tulu,ritesh,referee,champa,22
    kaustav,man,dip,gk,buro,alu,tulu,ritesh,referee,champa,23*
```

I want to get the 1st field and (in this example 'kaustav') when the value in the 3rd field is same in 2 or more records.

Also, please help me in getting the 1st field when the last field is greater than or equal to 20.

How can I achieve this in awk ? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello guys, I apologize that I missed out another part. I need another solution for which I have updated the original post. Could someone help me out on that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
awk -F, '++a[$1,$3] == 2 {print $1}' your.file
```

Output:

```
tulu
kaustav
```

---

Explanation:

In awk you can define a condition that must be true in order to execute the following action(s). Like this:

```
CONDITION { COMMAND }
```

In this is case our condition is: "Appeared the value of field 3 the second time for the name form field 1?". The command is to print the name from field 1 : `{ print $1 }`

To check the condition I'm using a multidimensional array. Note that awk cares about the initialization, I'm just using it. In that array I create an index for each value of field 1  that appears in the file and create and second, nested index with values of field 3 for that index which get counted using `++`. If this value reaches `2`, the condition gets true and the command will being executed.

Comment: I was just to post the same, with a small variation `a[$1 FS $3]`

Comment: I was told sometime that it may run in to trouble with array if value was not separated properly. Someone did give me an example, but I do not remember it now.  I guess the `,` should do.

Comment: Ok :) will keep the answer as is so far, for simplicity, but I'll keep it in mind ...

Comment: I am relatively new to scripting and all that more new to awk. May I know the logic for this solution please ? That would be very helpful.